# Show with a swarm of self-replicating robot spiders attempting to take over a starship

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship, robots

I don't really remember a lot about this show, other than that there was a swarm of self-replicating robot spiders that tried to take over a starship. I believe at some point several crew members holed themselves up inside a room with someone manning a machine gun stationed outside, trying to hold off the oncoming swarm.

This may have been something from the *Star Trek* franchise, but can't be sure: I [wasn't able to find anything with Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=star%20trek%20self-replicating%20spiders) anyway. I also have the impression that this is from a somewhat newer movie; the special effects were too well done to be from anything too old.

Comment: Are you sure it was a machine gun the person was manning, and not perhaps a robot with pulse blaster hands?  The only reason I ask is this sounds similar to a few scenes from the 1998 big budget film version of the tv show Lost In Space

Comment: I think it was a *Stargate: Atlantis* episode. I remember seeing that there was a spider queen or something like that. I never finished it as it was late and I had to go sleep. I think it was one of the final episodes from the end of one of the seasons. It was an hour+ long episode.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of one or more the *Stargate SG-1* episodes featuring [Replicators](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Replicator).  There are [a variety of types](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Replicator#Variations); the one pictured below is the 'spider' variant.

As mskfisher points out in [his comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41260/self-replicating-robot-spiders-attempt-to-take-over-a-starship#comment78401_41262), machine guns were often used by SG personnel to defend against the Replicators.

Replicators (of all the variants) were featured in many episodes.  [Links to key episode descriptions](https://www.gateworld.net/wiki/Replicators) can be found here.

[image: Spider replicator]

Comment: Notably, the characters on Stargate often used machine guns (with normal bullets) to defend against the Replicators.

Comment: +1 Specifically, going from "movie" and defending a room with a static machine gun, it sounds like the end of [The Ark of Truth](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate:_The_Ark_of_Truth).

Comment: There are many occurances of this in SG1, Jack and T'ealc have helped protect Thors ship, also the Deadalist was over run when the US government tried to covertly test out a replicator extinction programme which went very wrong and ending up in the character being also "borged" as his body was controlled by replicators.  The shot gun and "projectile" weapon was the preferred choice for positive effect against the replicators.

Comment: Also forgot one... They also once took over a submarine too... This was on the end of trying to defend an Asgard ship from the replicators.

Answer (score 15):

I think that this was [the *Lost in Space* film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_in_Space_%28film%29) (1998).  It has a scene where several people are running from robotic spiders and firing over their shoulders.  I think a child is remote-controlling a robot which is also firing at them.

Comment: Anyone know or recall if the spiders were self-replicating ?  This [Wiki](http://lostinspace.wikia.com/wiki/Space_Spider) briefly discusses but says nothing about self-replication.

Comment: @Stan: The spiders were organic beings, not robots, so they replicated the "traditional" way.

Comment: @jwodder Wonder if that's what the QP meant by self-replicating.

Comment: If the spiders were organic, isn't that at odds with the QPs statement that they were robotic ?  Unless we assume that the QPs memory is inaccurate.

Comment: They looked robotic in the film but they were actually organic. I thought it was close enough to suggest as an answer.

Comment: @Stefan Reasonable, I gave you +1 :)  We'll see if we get any feedback at all from the QP.

Comment: Nice try, but that's not it. There were way more of them than shown in that clip (think walls floors and ceilings covered in one massive swarm), and I'm pretty confident that they were robotic.

Comment: The previous link was dead so I edited in a trailer for the time being, but if you have another link to the scen, please edit it right back in :) (although I guess the spiders at ~0'56 in the trailer are the ones you were thinking about?)

Answer (score 6):

You aren't thinking of the single greatest film of all time "[Runaway](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088024/)" (1984) are you?

Gene Simmons Vs. Tom Selleck!!!

[Here are some fun clips](https://scyfilove.com/86/runaway-tom-selleck-and-gene-simmons/).

Comment: Nah, they didn't look like that. And the special effects were much better.

Comment: Shame it was not the answer as it is an awesome film!

Answer (score -2):

Are you thinking of the sentinels on The Matrix[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Note that this question already has an accepted answer, so you need to establish all of the details of the question are met for this to be considered as an alternate answer.  Can you point to a scene were someone with a machine gun was holding off the sentinels while other crew members hid in a room?